# Помочь со вложенными url на Джанго

Tags: django

Имеются url следующего вида:

- Сайт/категория
- Сайт/подкатегория
- сайт/статья

  class Category(MPTTModel):

  ```
   parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children',verbose_name='Главная категория')

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('blog:category_url', args=[self.slug])
  ```

  class Post(models.Model):

  ```
   rubrics = TreeManyToManyField(Category, related_name='rubrics', verbose_name='Категория')
       def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.slug ])
  ```

ссылки должны получиться такие

Сайт/категория

Сайт/категория/подкатегория

сайт/категория/подкатегория/статья

Сам принцип понимаю: при переходе, например, в подкатегорию, ссылки должны передаваться два параметра, это слаг главной категории и подкатегории. Во вьюхе, в функции должны определить эти параметры, но сделать это правильно не получается.

Прошу проконсультировать. За персональную консультацию заплачу (цену называете вы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в urls.py настрой пути

```
path(r'<slug:slug_category>', your_category_view, name='category_url'),
path(r'<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_sub>', your_sub_view, name='sub_url'),
path(r'<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_sub>/<slug:slug_artickle>', artickle_url, name='post_detail'),
```

дальше для категорий/подкатегорий

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
     if self.parent: 
         return reverse('blog:sub_url', args=[self.parent.slug, self.slug])
     else:
         return reverse('blog:category_url', args=[self.slug])
```

для статей, тут не совсем понятно как ты хочешь получать абсолютный урл, ведь у тебя идет привязка ManyToMany, следовательно таких урл может быть несколько и непонятно какой из них тебе нужен в данный момент, сделаю пока первый

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
     category = self.rubrics.first()
     return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[category.parent.slug, category.slug, self.slug ])
```